# Замыкания в javascript, почему не работает?

Tags: javascript, функции, замыкания

почему в ниже лежащей функции конечное значение переменной равно первоначальному? Хотя во внутренней функции данной переменной присвоено другое значение посредством замыкания? Как сделать, что бы сохранялось новое значение?

```
function s(){
  var a = 1;
  function d(c){
    console.log(c);
    c = 2;
    console.log(c);
  }
  d(a)
  console.log(a)
}
```

вывод в консоль:
s()
1
2
1

Comment: `c` — локальная переменная внутри функции без всяких замыканий, если надо изменить `a`, то так и пишите `a = 2;`

Comment: да у меня просто две переменные в верхней функции и обе эти переменные надо прогнать через внутреннюю функцию, поэтому невозможно во внутренней функции указать "а", надо через передачу аргументов(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что примитивные значения (строки, числа, булевы значения, null/undefined) передаются в качестве аргументов по значению, а не по ссылке.
Т.е. грубо говоря ваш аргумент `c` - это не ссылка на переменную `а`, это новая переменная `c`, со значением которое вы туда передали.
Если сделать объект, то он будет передаваться по ссылке -

```js
function s(){
  var a = {b:1};
  function d(c){
    console.log(c.b);
    c.b = 2;
    console.log(c.b);
  }
  d(a);
  console.log(a.b)
}

s();
```

Смысл замыкания как раз в том, что вы делаете одну функцию внутри другой, и из неё видно все локальные переменные родительской функции. вам не надо ничего никуда передавать чтоб с ними работать:

```js
function s(){
  var a = 1;
  function d(){
    console.log(a);
    a = 2;
    console.log(a);
  }
  d(a);
  console.log(a)
}
s();
```

> Замыкание — это особый вид функции. Она определена в теле другой
>   функции и создаётся каждый раз во время её выполнения. При этом
>   вложенная внутренняя функция содержит ссылки на локальные переменные
>   внешней функции.

(с) Википедия

Comment: точно спасибо большое!

Comment: @ahel73, вместо "Спасибо" тут принято плюсовать и, если ответ помог, принять его (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: это само собой просто пока галочку не могу поставить. вот жду)

Comment: @ahel73 Я дополнил ответ абзацем про замыкания

Comment: @Darth, перенесите код примеров в сниппеты, пожалуйста.